# Python http server wont start on aws

Tags: python, apache, http, amazon-web-services

I started a basic AWS instance (Amazon linux) and managed to SSH to it using putty. The public DNS was - ec2-(some_numbers).us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com and I generated a key file and that worked for sshing and scping. Now, I want to be able to create web apps hosted on this server. I followed the instructions on the link - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-deploy-app.html and ran the commands -

```
sudo yum groupinstall -y "Web Server" "PHP Support"
sudo service httpd start
```

At this point, they said I should have seen the apache test page when I type the public DNS in my browser, which I can. My ultimate aim is to have a python server that I have been developing on locally be hosted on this amazon linux instance. This I am unable to do. When I run my python file that contains the server and make it run on port 8888, I expect to be able to see the contents of my site when I type the (Public DNS):8888 in my browser. This doesn't seem to work. Does any one know what steps I need to take? My python code that starts the server -

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

server_addr = ('', g_SERVING_PORT) 
server = HTTPServer(server_addr, MyHTTPHandler)  # MyHTTPHandler is my HTTP SERVER implementation
server.serve_forever()
```

On my local machine/network, I am able to run this python file on the console and see the served pages using the internal ip.

Comment: are you inside a VPC? do you have a public IP? is your security group configured to let port 8888 in?

Comment: @Mircea Port 8888 not being configured was probably the problem. For now, I just used port 80 and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by running the python server on port 80. It is the default port to let traffic from the outside in, I think. This worked for me for now.